# Typo3 - Frontend 404 after Server Migration (also an URL Change)

Tags: migration, typo3

just for starters I have not worked at all with typo3 for at least 10 years.
But now I had to migrate a typo3 page (including a URL change). (This migration prozess also doubles as a test for the backup I'm doing with those folders, files and the db dump)

So I copied the folders fileadmin, uploads, typo3conf, the ext_localconf.php file and made db dump.

On the new server I installed a fresh typo3 (same version as the one on the old server 11.5.31), uploaded the the folders, the file and imported the mysql dump into the new database. Changed the DB in the ext_localconf file and launched the backend. There I changed the baseURL in the template view of the tree in the root page to the new base URL.

This were all the steps that I remembered when migrating a typo3 page. But the frontend still only show a 404 Page Not Found error:
The page did not exist or was inaccessible. Reason: The requested page does not exist (in typo3 design)

Can anyone point me to the step I forgot or to a step-by-step instruction to migrate a page in these circumstances for dummies?

copied the folders fileadmin, uploads, typo3conf, the ext_localconf.php file and made db dump and changed baseURL in tempalte view of page in backend

EDIT:
What makes this difficult is that the page owner did not give me permission to put his URL in here so I had to black it out in all the screenshots. I changed the URL in SiteManagement and I changed it at the root page for the template. (as seen in the screenshots) Are there other positions where I need to change it?

[URL in Site Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIXMI.png)

[URL in Root Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfGhA.png)

Comment: So, currently, the copy has _another_ domain/url? Over the last 10 years, the SiteConfiguration has been introduced for mapping domains to (root-)pages: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/Basics.html